# Statistics - Confidence Intervals - $P(X>1)$

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I'm not sure how to solve the following:
$X_1,\dotsc,X_n \sim U(0,2p)$

What is the confidence interval to the probability that $X>1$?

I've managed to find the CI for $p$ using the estimator of $p$, but I'm clueless regarding the above

a similar follow-up: 
if $X_1,\dotsc, X_n \sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$,
how to construct the CI of the probability of $X$ being $0$?

Comment: Can you express P(X > 1) in terms of p?

Comment: I'm unsure if that is your intention but assuming that P(X>1)=(2p-1)/2p ?

Comment: Let $\tau = P(X > 1) = 1 - 1/2p$. Can you manipulate inequality to get CI for $\tau$ from your CI for $p$?

Comment: not entirely sure how I can do it. I assume that what is necessary is the form $P(something<p<something)$. I'm playing with some inequalities that I know but I can't get to that form

Comment: If you have a CI for $p$, you should already know the 'somethings.'

Comment: I'm new to math and statistics so if you can please provide more detail it would help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details of Comment: From what you say, I assume you have lower and upper bounds for a 2-sided 95% CI for $p$. Say that these bounds are $L$ and $U$. Then
$$P(L < p < U) = .95.$$
Manipulate the inequality $L < p < U$ to get $2L < 2p < 2U,$
then $-1/2L < - 1/2p < -1/2U$ and finally
$$P(1-1/2L < 1 - 1/2p = \tau < 1-1/2U) = .95,$$
which would give the 95% CI $(1-1/2L, 1 - 2/U)$ for $\tau = P(X > 1) = 1 - 1/2p.$

All of this depends on what you have told me. I have not checked
the correctness of that. I'm just filling in details of my comment as you requested.

This is not fundamentally different (or more difficult) than manipulating the probability statement 
$$P(-1.96 < Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} < 1.96) = .95$$
to get the CI $\bar X \pm 1.96 \sigma/\sqrt{n}$ for $\mu$ when
sampling from normal data with $\sigma$ known.